# Posting to company page on Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-wall

I have a company page where my client posts the latest company info and newly available products to their wall. They wanted to automate this somewhat so this post happens without someone having to log into Facebook.

http://yaplex.com/facebook-sdk-how-post-wall-55/

The link above shows a working example of how to post to the wall of a Facebook app using the apps `AppId` and `AppSecretKey`.

However, how can we do the same but post to our company page which, as far as we know, doesn't have an `AppId` or `AppSecret`?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open an application on facebook, a user would have to 'install' that application and give it `offline_access` permissions.  Once you have that permission you don't need the user to be logged in to publish stories on his/her behalf. 
If you want the stories to be posted on behalf of a page then you'll have to do a similar process, only request the `manage_pages` permission, with that permission you can retrieve an access token for the page and using that token all posts will be on behalf of the page (or the application)